# How do I use the value of a field that comes from a nested select to calculate the value of another field?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm doing a query in Firebird to list fields from several tables on a single query, how do I use the value of a field that comes from a nested select to calculate the value of another field?

Let me show you.

Here everything goes great,

```sql
SELECT c.CVE_ART AS "Item Code", 
    c.DESCR AS "Item Description", 
    c.EXIST AS "Qty on Hand", 
    c.ULT_COSTO AS "Last Purchase Price", 
    c.COSTO_PROM "Average Cost", 
    (select h.precio from PRECIO_X_PROD01 h where h.cve_Art = c.cve_Art and h.CVE_PRECIO = 2) as "Sales Price",  
    (Select sum(z.CANT) from PAR_COMPC01 z inner join COMPC01 v on z.CVE_DOC = v.CVE_DOC where c.CVE_ART= z.CVE_ART and v.FECHAELAB > '01.01.2020' ) as "Yearly Purchases Qty",
    (Select sum(q.CANT) from PAR_FACTF01 q inner join FACTF01 p on q.CVE_DOC = p.CVE_DOC where c.CVE_ART = q.CVE_ART and (p.FECHAELAB > '01.01.2020' and p.STATUS != 'C')) as "Total Sales Qty",
    (Select sum(q.CANT) from PAR_FACTF01 q inner join FACTF01 p on q.CVE_DOC = p.CVE_DOC where c.CVE_ART = q.CVE_ART and (p.FECHAELAB > '01.01.2020' and p.STATUS != 'C'))/12 as "Monthly Sales Qty Average"
    
FROM FACTF01 a 
JOIN PAR_FACTF01 b 
ON A.CVE_DOC = B.CVE_DOC
INNER JOIN INVE01 c
on b.CVE_ART = c.CVE_ART

where b.CVE_ART = 'GX420P'
group by c.CVE_ART, c.DESCR, c.EXIST, c.ult_costo, c.COSTO_PROM
```

And this is my output

[image: Output]

I need another field to calculate how "many months worth of inventory" I have, using these fields C.EXIST/"Monthly Sales Qty Average" -- I use the full formula for the "Monthly Sales Average". However, I get a nonsense value, how can I approach this different?

I need this output

[image: Needed Output]

I will need do this for other fields, so any solution I can repeat for other fields would be great.

Comment: 1) for `Select sum(z.CANT)` and `Select sum(z.CANT)` you better use `Left Join` and `group by` and CTE (SQL Common Table Expressions) than nested selects. 2) show sample data and sample query on http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0  3) what exactyly should be that formula for the column missing frm your query?

Comment: Also, why do you need to do it in SQL ? `I will need do this for other fields` - jsut do it in report generator, you get sample data, you may add some virtual columns, all you need is to take few data columns and multiply/divide. In client software it can be done as well. If not you can even do `select from select`

Comment: Please provide sample data and a clear description of how the values should be derived.